# call a separate job/shell file and wait for it to complete execution before continuing further, in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I intend to call a shell script from the main script and wait for it to complete before processing the main script further,

I have tried doing

```
xyz_Sh &
while [[ $cnt -gt 0 ]] ; do
cnt=`ps -ef| grep "xyz_Sh" |grep -v grep |wc -l`
done
```

I also tried using wait as

```
. xyz_Sh & 
wait_id=$!
wait $wait_id
```

but in this case the control does not return back to the main routine, the script stops after executes xyz_Sh, what am I missing here ?

Thanks

Ali

Comment: If you provide more of your script, we can provide better answers.  What is it that's not being executed after `xyz_Sh` finishes?

Comment: The purpose of appending '&' to the command is to prevent your main script from waiting.  If you want to wait, just stop using '&'.

Comment: Hi Thanks, the thing is that when I tired to call it directly from the main shell, I found that the script was just exiting after it finished xyz_sh, after I call the script I have a few additional db updates, and finally I am calling another script lmn_sh from the main shell script. Thanks Ali

Answer (score 1):

Unless something is put into the background in `xyz_Sh` then the default shell behavior should do exactly what you want.

In a shell script, a command isn't executed until the previous command has ended, so:

```
xyz_Sh
//do other stuff
```

should work exactly as you want it to.

If, on the other hand, `xyz_Sh` *does* put things in the background, then you should alter `xyz_Sh` to wait for all of its processes to finish before exiting.  This can be done with the `wait` command.

Comment: Hi Thanks, the thing is that when I tired to call it directly from the main shell, I found that the script was just exiting after it finished xyz_sh, after I call the script I have a few additional db updates, and finally I am calling another script lmn_sh from the main shell script. Thanks Ali